# How to extend a power outlet from an existing outdoor light

Tags: receptacle, light-fixture, wire, light

There is an outdoor light owned by HOA, located outside of the door of my apartment unit. And I'd like to install a security camera near the light. There is no outlet there, and How can I extend an outlet from the existing light?

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Do you have the right or permission to interfere with their light?

Comment: Agreed, you can’t usually add an electrical outlet to somebody else’s electrical service without permission (who pays the bill for what’s plugged into it?)

Comment: Also I haven't seen any security camera that require 120V power. Isn't it usually low voltage and powered from a remote source?

Comment: just use a socket extender with outlets, then a dc power brick; no modification needed; just unscrew and put back in the bulb when you move.

Comment: i chatted with HOA, they are actually fine with a socket extender! haha thanks guys